# Spring Integration Test for Hibernate.initialized for Lazy Loaded Collections

Tags: hibernate, integration-testing, spring-test

I have a lazy loaded @OneToMany relationship which I have initialized using Hibernate.initialize(). Here are my Entities.

**Pet.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pets")
public class Pet {

@Column(name = "birth_date")
private Date birthDate;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
private PetType type;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
private Owner owner;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pet", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Visit> visits;
```

}

**Visit.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "visits")
public class Visit {

@Column(name = "visit_date")
private Date date;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pet_id")
private Pet pet;
```

}

I have JPA Repositories for these Entities, PetRepository, OwnerRepository and VisitRepository.

I have one @Service class.

**OwnerServiceImpl.java**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void updateOwnerPetVisits(int ownerId) throws DataAccessException {

Owner owner = ownerRepository.findById(ownerId);

int petId = owner.getPet().getPetId();

Pet pet = findPetById(petId);

Hibernate.initialize(pet.getVisits());

OwnerResource ownerResource = new OwnerResource();
ownerResource.setPet(pet);
ownerResource.setPetVisits(pet.getVisits().size());

}

private Pet findPetById(int id) throws DataAccessException {
return petRepository.findById(id);
}
```

OwnerResource is a simple DTO.

**OwnerResource.java**

```
public class OwnerResource {
 private Pet pet;
 private int petVisits
}
```

Now I was trying to write the Integration Test for the OwnerServiceImpl#updateOwnerPetVisits.

**OwnerServiceJPAIntegrationTests.java**

```
   @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/spring-jpa.xml"})
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   public class OwnerServiceJPAIntegrationTests {

     @Autowired
     OwnerRepository ownerRepository;

     @Autowired
     PetRepository petRepository;

     @Autowired
     OwnerService ownerService;


     @Test
     public void testUpdateOwnerPetVisits(){

      Owner owner = createNewOwner();

      int petId = owner.getPet().getPetId();

      Pet pet = findPetById(petId);

      assertFalse(Hibernate.isInitialized(pet.getVisits());

      ownerService.updateOwnerPetVisits(owner.getOwnerId());

      assertTrue(Hibernate.isInitialized(pet.getVisits());

    }


private Owner createNewOwner()  {

Pet pet  = new Pet();
pet.setBirthDate(today);
petRepository.add(pet); // entityManager.persist();

Visit visit1 = new Visit();
visit1.setDate(today);
visit1.setDescription("T");
visit1.setPet(pet); 
visitRepository.add(visit1); // entityManager.persist();

Visit visit2 = new Visit();
visit2.setDate(today);
visit2.setDescription("P");
visit2.setPet(pet); 
visitRepository.add(visit2); // entityManager.persist();

Owner owner = new Owner();
owner.setPet(pet);
ownerRepository.add(owner); // entityManager.persist();
}
```

This works fine.

Now if I **remove the call, Hibernate.initialize(pet.getVisits());**

from OwnerServiceImpl#updateOwnerPetVisits. The **test case should fail now but it still works**.

Comment: What does createNewOwner() do?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the entities in createNewOwner() so why should they be lazy loaded?

If you want to simulate lazy loading you must clear the EntityManger persistence context before calling findPetById()

```
 @Test
 public void testUpdateOwnerPetVisits(){

  Owner owner = createNewOwner();

  int petId = owner.getPet().getPetId();

  // Clears the persistence context
  entityManager.clear();

  Pet pet = findPetById(petId);

  assertFalse(Hibernate.isInitialized(pet.getVisits());

  ownerService.updateOwnerPetVisits(owner.getOwnerId());

  assertTrue(Hibernate.isInitialized(pet.getVisits());

}
```

Comment: Can  you be more specific about what methods to call on what objects exactly?

Comment: I added the example code. But I don't see what was not clear before?

Comment: Calling the `clear()` method on the `EntityManager`. Thanks for clarifying.